# Diffrence between dataweave and datamapper

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave

I am new to Mule ESB, i have started working on Dataweave Transformer. I want to know what are the differences between the Datamapper and Dataweave transformer. And why Dataweave came into play, what were the shortcomings of Datamapper.

Answer (score 5):

The DataWeave engine is a tool/component allows you to transform data to and from any kind of format (XML, CSV, JSON, Pojos, Maps, etc. This tool is introduced from Mule 3.7. It is more easy to use than a DataMapper.
ref:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation
It generates a `.dwl` transformation file

DataMapper also used  to map and transform data to and from any kind of format, but from Mule version 3.7 it is getting depreciated replaced by DataWeave.
ref:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/datamapper-concepts
It generates `.grf` mapping files

You can get some more reference on Datamapper to DataWeave here :- http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-studio-dev/getting-started-with-dataweave-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Anirban mentioned, remember that DataMapper will be removed in Mule 4.0.

Also, DataWeave is fully featured modeling language and you can write any kind of transformations with it. Its easy, simple and follows json like syntax. Whereas DataMapper transformations were not so easy to modify and create.

For any new developments, it may make sense to use DataWeave.

Answer (score 0):

Data Weave and Data Mapper are used to transform your message from various kind of format like CSV, XML, JSON etc.
Data Weave has JSON like syntax and it is much powerful and faster than Data Mapper.
Data Weave Transformation has been coupled with Mule Runtime to ensure higher performance, adopted language first approach and designed the language with JSON like Syntax.

More details can be found at http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/why-dataweave-matters/

Answer (score 0):

In Simple words, both are used to transform your data into various formats. Data Weave has more features and simple to use compared to Data Mapper. Also, Data mapper is deprecated after Mule 3.7.